# why latex subscript prints signs

Tags: latex

hi i am using latex and texmaker to do the following:

```
             $\mathcal{a( X, Y )= a_i \circ a_j}$
```

which i expect to get 
                a(X,Y)= a subscript {i} circle a subscript {j}

but instead i get weird signs instead for a's (on the right side of equation), i and j ...can you tell me why? thanks...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that \mathcal only works on upper case letters.

Answer (score 1):

never mind i did

```
          $a(X,Y)=a_i \circ a_j$
```

it solved the problem.

thanks anyways!